# Why does "margin: 0 auto" delete the white space in my div? How can I center a div with its white space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I've sat on this problem for quite a while now and don't know what to do.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, be gentle, lol.

I want to do something very basic - just to center the div (marked with red border) so it's on the same position as the header div (also marked with red border), see screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvPOF.jpg

If I give the div a margin of "0 auto", it will remove the white space that's on the right side of the div, why does it do that? Here's the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LBEp.jpg

How should I center the div, am I approaching the problem from a wrong angle?

Here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div class="header-bg">
    <div class="width">
        <div class="width2">
            <p class="header-title"><span class="gold-text">CAN’T HURT ME:</span> MASTER YOUR MIND AND DEFY THE ODDS</p>
            <p class="header-text">Can’t Hurt Me: Master Your Mind and Defy the Odds chronicles David Goggins’ incredible life from perpetual victim to active duty Navy SEAL to world class ultra athlete and world record holder. <a href="http://geni.us/canthurtme" target="_blank">Now available at these fine retailers</a>.<p>
        </div>
                
        <div class="buttons width2">
            <div class="button-1">
                <p>Buy the Book</p>
            </div>
            <div class="button-2">
                <p>About David</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.width {
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.width2 {
    max-width: 500px;
}

.header-bg {
    background: black url('../img/header.jpg') no-repeat center / cover;
    height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: @Dexterians awesome, that works! Thank you for your answer and most importantly, the explanation!

Comment: Hey @ffrg - I have translated it in to an answer. If you're satisfied please mark my response as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What element are you applying the `margin: 0 auto`?

I think your `max-width` on those divs is what is causing your issue. Add a `min-width` or just set `width` - MAX-WIDTH means it can be anywhere from 0px up to 1000px (for example) depending on the screen size... so if your screen is only 400px wide, it will be 400px wide. If your screen is 1200px, the div will lock at 1000px - so basically when you're applying your margin; the margin is shrinking your box thus removing white space (as it isn't breaking the `max-width` rule due to no `min-width` rule being set).

TLDR; change `max-width` on those divs to just be `width` and you might see it'll play nicer to what you're after.